# Rim joist support for DWV hole

Tags: framing

I have a 2nd floor stairwell with a 9' 2x10 rim joist on one side. I'd like to attach a sister joist to this rim joist; drill a 3.5" hole through it and the sister joist; and use a Metwood 2810HR joist hole reinforcer plate on the sister joist. The 2810HR plate is code approved. Note that I can't put one of the existing rim joist because it is 16" long and won't fit in the space between 16" OC joists, and, if I put it one the other side of the existing rim joist, I can't attach the sister joist to it.

My question - Will the sister joist provide code-approved support to the existing rim joist and it's hole?

Thanks
[image: Green joists are new ones.]

Comment: It would be very helpful to [edit] your question to include a sketch of the work to help people visualize what your plan is.

Comment: That's much more clear. It does, though, now beg the question what the heck is the hole for? That would be an odd place for a plumbing stack...